# How to quench and get rid of P2S5?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I am using $\ce{P2S5}$ as a thionating agent on ketones and amides. The reaction works very well, however there is little to no information on how to safely quench and get rid of the unreacted $\ce{P2S5}$. The procedures I use simply rotavap the crude product and recrystallize the desired product, which works great, but some unreacted $\ce{P2S5}$ is always left at the bottom of the flask. I read about people adding a dilute solution of $\ce{K2CO3}$ in order to hydrolyse the remaining $\ce{P2S5}$ into phosphoric acid and $\ce{H2S}$ but I'm not sure how safe this is. I'm working on less than $\pu{10 g}$ scale.

Comment: People underestimate how toxic H2S is. A quench into aqueous oxidant e.g. Oxone will prevent H2S formation and hydrolyse the P2S5

Comment: Which product is obtained instead of H2S?

Comment: Depends on exactly which oxidant is used. Sulfite anion would be the most likely.

Comment: Did you see Bergmann's approach to use the adduct of pyridine and $\ce{P2S5}$? The reagent obtained by a brief reflux (crystalline, less smelly than $\ce{P2S5}$) is used in e.g.  MeCN.  The eventual addition of water decomposes the excess into a water soluble pyridinium phosphorothioate. [2011JOC1546](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo101865y) (introduction) and Kingi and Bergman in [2016JOC7711](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.joc.6b01346) (an application by them) though so far at scale of about $\pu{1 mmol}$.  It could be still more efficient that Lawesson's reagent.